# Parallel multiway merge sort for Unix

Tags: sorting, unix, parallel-processing

I have searched to see if I could find a parallel multiway merge sort that would run on a Unix command line. I could find none.

GNU Sort uses merge sort, but the final merge is single threaded. `parsort` is also single threaded in the final merge step.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Parallel_multiway_merge_sort shows how it is possible to parallelize the final merge step.

Before I spend time on implementing the multithreaded algorithm from Wikipedia:

- Is this already done?
- If there is not a command line tool for Unix: Is there at least a library that does the final merge step in parallel (in other words: can I simply make a command line wrapper for an existing library?)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*- Is this already done?*

As of posting date - nope. So you'd be the 1st one

*- If there is not a command line tool for Unix: Is there at least a library that does the final merge step in parallel (in other words: can I simply make a command line wrapper for an existing library?)?*

A `GNU parallel extension` to the `Standard C++ Library` includes a file called [multiway_mergesort.h](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/libstdc++/api/a00967_source.html)  which implements a `parallel multiway merge sort`

`MPDMSort` uses the `OpenMP` library to develop a parallel implementation of the algorithm which  could be used to create a command line wrapper for an existing implementation of `parallel multiway merge sort`.
Just some starter thoughts

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this isn't done in practice because merging sorted lists, even in a multiway merge, is really fast, so it's likely that a single CPU core can saturate the available I/O bandwidth.

To answer your question with another question: why do you believe sort's performance could be significantly improved by optimizing the final merge?

Comment: Because I have tested. On my 64 core sorting 100 M lines most of the wall clock time is spent in this final merge. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/579251/how-to-use-parallel-to-speed-up-sort-for-big-files-fitting-in-ram/579252#579252